# Docker Network Nginx Keycloak Integration not working properly(Ubuntu 19)

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, keycloak, docker-swarm

I haven't been able to get Keycloak and Nginx to work within the same Docker network:

Sequence of events:

1. https://localhost takes me to the application homepage.
2. When I click on the login button:
   I see the following URL in the browser:
   https://localhost/auth/realms/bizmkc/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=bizmapp&redirect_uri=&state=26ce2075-8099-4960-83e8-508e40c585f3&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=b57ca43a-ed93-48ab-9c96-591cd6378de9
   which gives me a 404.
3. Nginx logs show the following:

```
2020/04/13 09:58:38 [error] 7#7: *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /auth/realms/bizmkc/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=bizmapp&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin&state=26ce2075-8099-4960-83e8-508e40c585f3&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=b57ca43a-ed93-48ab-9c96-591cd6378de9 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:9443/auth/realms/bizmkc/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=bizmapp&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin&state=26ce2075-8099-4960-83e8-508e40c585f3&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=b57ca43a-ed93-48ab-9c96-591cd6378de9", host: "localhost", referrer: "https://localhost/login"
2020/04/13 09:58:38 [error] 7#7: *19 open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 10.0.0.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /auth/realms/bizmkc/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=bizmapp&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin&state=26ce2075-8099-4960-83e8-508e40c585f3&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=b57ca43a-ed93-48ab-9c96-591cd6378de9 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:9443/auth/realms/bizmkc/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=bizmapp&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Flogin&state=26ce2075-8099-4960-83e8-508e40c585f3&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=b57ca43a-ed93-48ab-9c96-591cd6378de9", host: "localhost", referrer: "https://localhost/login"
```

4. If I run Nginx on its own outside the Docker network, then the browser URL

```
https://localhost/auth/realms/bizmkc/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=bizmapp&redirect_uri=<redirecxt_uri>&state=26ce2075-8099-4960-83e8-508e40c585f3&response_mode=fragment&response_type=code&scope=openid&nonce=b57ca43a-ed93-48ab-9c96-591cd6378de9 correctly takes me to the Keycloak realm login page.
```

I don't know why URL redirection for the ports doesn't work within the Docker network.

My nginx.conf file

```
# nginx.vh.default.conf  --  docker-openresty
#
# This file is installed to:
#   `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`
#
# It tracks the `server` section of the upstream OpenResty's `nginx.conf`.
#
# This config (and any other configs in `etc/nginx/conf.d/`) is loaded by
# default by the `include` directive in `/usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`.
#
# See https://github.com/openresty/docker-openresty/blob/master/README.md#nginx-config-files
#



# log if  only it's a new user  with no cookie. From https://www.nginx.com/blog/sampling-requests-with-nginx-conditional-logging/
    map $cookie_SESSION $logme {
         ""  1;  
         default   0;
    }

server {
    listen      80;   #listen for all the HTTP requests
    server_name localhost;
   # return      301         https://localhost;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost; # same server name  as  port  80 is fine

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssldir/ssl.crt; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssldir/ssl.key;


    charset utf-8;


    # log a user only one time. If cookie is  null,  it's a new user
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$logme;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    # Optional: If the application does not generate a session cookie, we 
    # generate our own
    add_header Set-Cookie SESSION=1;


# MUST USE TRAILING HASH IN  https://localhost:9443/  AND  IT WILL NOT ADD  BIZAUTH ****important
# Default keycloak configuration points to CONTECT  auth   in standalone/configuration/standalone.xml. So use  auth

    location /auth {
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_pass https://localhost:9443;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    location / {
        root   /usr/local/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
   # following is needed for  angular  pathlocation   strategy
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /mpi {


        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

 #       client_max_body_size       10m;
 #       client_body_buffer_size    128k;

 #       proxy_connect_timeout      90;
 #       proxy_send_timeout         90;
 #       proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }

    location /npi {


        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }


    location /tilla/ {
         proxy_pass https://www.google.com/;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/local/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           /usr/local/openresty/nginx/html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}

    # On error pages,  this  will prevent  showing version  number
    #server_tokens off;
}
```

keycloak-nginx.yaml

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  nginx:
      name: nginx
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.17.7-alpine
    domainname: localhost
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      nginx:
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx/html:/usr/local/nginx/html
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./nginx/ssldir:/etc/nginx/ssldir:ro

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:8.0.1
    domainname: localhost
    ports:
      - "9443:8443"
    networks:
      nginx:
    volumes:
      #      - ${USERDIR}/keycloak/config.json:/config.json
      - /mnt/disks/vol1/kcthemes:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes
      #- /mnt/disks/vol1/ssldir:/etc/x509/https
    environment:
      # https://geek-cookbook.funkypenguin.co.nz/recipes/keycloak/setup-oidc-provider/
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=aaaa
      #      - KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/config.json
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_ADDR=keycloak-db
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=myuberpassword
      # This is required to run keycloak behind traefik
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME=localhost
      # Tell Postgress what user/password to create
      - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myuberpassword
      - ROOT_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
      - KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG

    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - keycloak-db

  # https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres
  keycloak-db:
    image: postgres:12.1-alpine
    ports:
      - target: 5432
        published: 5432
    networks:
      nginx:
    volumes:
      - ./kc_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - DB_VENDOR=postgres
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_ADDR=keycloak-db
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=.
      # This is required to run keycloak behind traefik
      - KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME=localhost
      # Tell Postgress what user/password to create
      - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myuberpassword
    restart: "no"

  keycloak-db-backup:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      nginx:
    volumes:
      - ${USERDIR}/keycloak/database-dump:/dump
    environment:
      - PGHOST=keycloak-db
      - PGUSER=keycloak
      - PGPASSWORD=myuberpassword
      - BACKUP_NUM_KEEP=7
      - BACKUP_FREQUENCY=1d
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c 'bash -s <<EOF
      trap "break;exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
      sleep 2m
      while /bin/true; do
        pg_dump -Fc > /dump/dump_\`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S\`.psql
        (ls -t /dump/dump*.psql|head -n $$BACKUP_NUM_KEEP;ls /dump/dump*.psql)|sort|uniq -u|xargs rm -- {}
        sleep $$BACKUP_FREQUENCY
      done
      EOF'
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - nginx
```

Command used to run this
 docker stack deploy -c keycloak-nginx.yaml kc

docker info

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 5
  Running: 3
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 2
 Images: 20
 Server Version: 19.03.6
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: pusagcsjon73mkvjxn2wx9bkz
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: ibxcgupiut3apyhwyn78anycj
  Managers: 1
  Nodes: 1
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 192.168.0.145
  Manager Addresses:
   192.168.0.145:2377
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 
 runc version: 
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0-96-generic
 Operating System: Linux Mint 19.1
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 6
 Total Memory: 31.28GiB
 Name: Yogi-Linux
 ID: YTU6:VKGZ:42ED:QJNQ:34RU:IWAU:L5UL:PJP2:2FJG:FYZC:FRUC:6XNB
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  localhost:32000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Please, try to post a minimal configuration with your issue. You've got paths to your own application in nginx configuration file, in the docker compose file you've got the postgres configuration.. Try to reproduce it using minimal nginx and keycloak configurations.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` in the container is not the same `localhost` which you see on the OS level, so:

- don't force keycloak service to be "localhost" (`domainname`,`KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME`)
- proxy pass /auth to keycloak service (not to `localhost`)

```
        proxy_pass https://keycloak:9443;
```

OR:

run all containers in the OS network namespace (`--net=host`, but generally it isn't recommended) and then `localhost` in the container will be the same as your OS `localhost`.

Comment: What should be the KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME instead of localhost? I made the changes you suggested. Now I get this error from Nginx: I've Verizon so this is their fallout DNS address 92.242.140.21 2020/04/13 21:25:54 [info] 7#7: *1 epoll_wait() reported that client prematurely closed connection, so upstream connection is closed too while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.0.2, server: localhost, request: "GET /auth/realms/master/account HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://92.242.140.21:8443/auth/realms/master/account", host: "localhost"